# How to exclude a specific port from Nginx

Tags: ssh, nginx, ssh-tunnel

I have two apps running on the same server, `app1` and `app2`;
but for `app2` I don't want to serve it with Nginx.
I want it to be accessible only through ssh tunneling.

I have configured Nginx to capture the `domain.name/app1` and redirect it to `localhost:app_port1`;
and I am running app2 as `127.0.0.1:app_port2` and I want it to be accessible only with `ssh` as:

```
ssh -L3000:localhost:3000 remote_machine
```

But still nginx is capturing the traffic for `localhost:3000` and hence the ssh tunnel cannot work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I don't understand the problem

Which one of app_port1 or app_port2 is the port 3000?

If the apps are running on different ports, what is the problem?
What is preventing the ssh tunnel to work properly?

What is Nginx doing wrong?